# how to use +operator proper in object combinining?

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

```
class Point {

private:    

    float xcord;
    float ycord; }



class Line{
friend class Nonlinear;

protected:  

float dist;
Point *p1,*p2;  

virtual const Line& operator+(const Line& l) const;
```

for virtual operator+ how can i update the new p1 and p2 values of newly created object? 
i can update the dist value  by using

```
Line *l1=(Line*)&l
l1->dist=dist+l.dist
```

but i didnt understand why i am getting stuck on combining Points.

Comment: `operator+` would normally return by value. Having it return by reference makes little sense.

Comment: Wait, are you saying you plan to update **the operand** of the operator? That makes even less sense. When I write `x = a + b;` I don't expect `a` or `b` to change their values. Start from the beginning: how do you plan to **use** that operator, once implemented? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `Line` having its points as pointer members (as opposed to values), means that this is either: a) hard to answer without context because the relationship between `Line` and `Point` is fairly complex. Or b) coded in a way that makes implementing the `+operator()` a lot harder than it has to.